# Persist typescript renaming process in Vue Router lazy load routes

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue router with default import as:

```
import Home from '@/views/home';

{
  path: '/home',
  component: Home
}
```

Our project is now pretty big, and we need lazy loading, which will be like:

```
{
  path: '/home',
  component: import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ '@/views/home')
}
```

That's ok but I need typescript support for auto import and if I move the component then it should update the path, because that's a cool feature of TypeScript, and it works well with default imports. Is there any way that it can work in lazy load imports too?